# How Can I find latitude and longitude of my Windows Phone 7.5

Tags: windows, windows-phone-7

Can I access my phone Geo-location.

Will my phone give me my present latitude and longitude.

Answer (score 2):

The best solution would be , use Bing Maps API INTEGRATION , the api would return the coordinates based on the location

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. See this [post.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dragoman/archive/2010/09/21/wp7-code-using-the-geolocation-api.aspx)

use the `System.Device.Location;` namespace.

One more [post.](http://albrecht-schmidt.blogspot.com/2011/03/wp7-tutorial-part-3-using-location.html)

Comment: Could We Get ISP Provider Tower Details(Such As Time Zone) using windows phone Apps

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.device.location.aspx  Check the docs.

Comment: Really you have helped me.. Wasted a day finding a good solution for this. You gave me a correct link which i was looking for